# Evitar el acceso a un archivo php con htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Tengo la siguiente problemática, tengo una carpeta llamada mi-perfil dentro hay otra carpeta llamada mascota con un archivo mascota.php

Tengo un href="mi-perfil/mascota/1/copito"

Luego realizo la interpretación con htaccess de la siguiente forma

```
RewriteRule ^mi-perfil/mascota/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)$ mi-perfil/mascota/mascota.php?id=$1&nombre=$2
```

Todo bien hasta ahí, cargan los estilos css se muestran los datos según la consulta a la base de datos y las variables que se pasan por la url.

Ahora, quiero que si por algún motivo alguien escribe en el navegador la url "mi-perfil/mascota/mascota.php" sea redireccionado a otra página, ya que en teoría no se están pasando las variables y al ser una carpeta un nivel más arriba los estilos tampoco cargan, entonces quiero evitar que alguien entre a esa url

Answer (score 0):

Podrías agregar una regla que redireccione únicamente cuando no tiene el parámetro `id` por ejemplo:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)id[=&] [NC]
RewriteRule ^mi-perfil/mascota/mascota\.php$ mi-perfil/mascota/tu-otra-pagina.php [R=302,L,NC]
```

Comment: Me sirve lo que me has mencionado, pero el inconveniente que tengo es que me redirige a esta ruta, mencionar que estoy en local "http://192.168.0.2/C:/wamp64/www/proyecto/mi-perfil/mascota/tu-otra-pagina.php" me gustaria que quede asi "192.168.0.2/proyecto/mi-perfil/mascota/tu-otra-pagina.php"

Comment: @JonathanAlarcon eso no tiene que ver con esta regla ni con la pregunta sino con la configuración de Apache... No tengo tan claro de dónde toma el `C:\wamp64` como base del proyecto, pero hay 3 cosas que haría: (1) agregar esta línea antes: `RewriteBase /` (2) Probar poner la barra también al principio de la redirección `/mi-perfil/mascota/tu-otra-pagina.php` y (3) revisar el .conf de Apache, buscando que esté bien definido el document root y demás carpetas (esa parte no la sé, voy viendo 1 a 1 cuando tengo que editar el conf)

Answer (score 0):

Con esto debería servirte:

```
RewriteRule ^mi-perfil/mascota/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)$ mi-perfil/mascota/mascota.php?id=$1&nombre=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^mi-perfil/mascota/(.*)$ lugar-donde-sera-redirigido.php [L]
```

También podrías impedir el acceso directo a la carpeta mi-perfil agregando un .htaccess con lo siguiente:

```
Options -Indexes
```